# Creating a Function to use for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

How can I create a function that squares the specific column value from a dataframe in pandas?

it should be like as you see below

`def func(dataframe,column,value)`

Comment: You don't need to use a function. You can just do: df['column name'] = df['column name']**2

Comment: I know that but I have to use that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have dataframe named `df`

Just create a function:-

```
def pow(data,column,val):
    return data[column]**val
```

Now just call the function and pass the series,and val as parameter:-

```
func(df,'col3',2)
```

Between you can do this without creating a function just by:-

```
df['column name']**2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..

Yes, I have a dataframe called `df`

Your answers work too but i have to define that function as `def func(dataframe,column,value)`

Comment: Without using 'value' i figured out how to do it but i couldn't make it with 'value'.

It is how it is without 'value'


`def func(df,column):

    df[column]=df[column]*df[column]


    return df`

Comment: Thanks for helping so much but it's still not the one i need :(......your functions has data,val.... i need df,columnname,value

Comment: Heyyy :).... I did a small change to your last edit and it works... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: that's great............btw if this answer helps you then try considering  accept this answer thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you wanted to square only those values in the `column` column *which are equal to `value` parameter:*

```
def func(dataframe, column, value):
    s = dataframe[column]
    dataframe[column] = s.mask(s == value, lambda x: x**2)
```

*Note:*

This function changes the dataframe *in place*, so in concordance with Python conventions it returns the `None` value. (Why? Because there is no `return` statement.)

---

*The explanation:*

1. In the first command (in the body of the function definition) we assign the appropriate column (i.e. a series) to the variable `s`.
2. In the second command we apply the method `.mask()` with 2 arguments:

   - The first argument is a *condition* for using the second argument,
   - the second argument is a *function* (which is used only for elements *satisfying the condition given in the first argument*).

---

*A test:*

```
>>> df
```

> ```
>    A  B  C  D
> 0  4  4  3  4
> 1  3  3  4  4
> 2  4  4  2  2
> 3  3  2  3  4
> 4  4  2  4  3
> ```

```
>>> func(df, "D", 4)
>>> df
```

> ```
>    A  B  C   D
> 0  4  4  3  16
> 1  3  3  4  16
> 2  4  4  2   2
> 3  3  2  3  16
> 4  4  2  4   3
> ```

Comment: You're welcome. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)